# Lettre officielle. Abréviations et structure

Tags: traduction, anglais, correspondance

I read a text in French related to honorary consular.

First of all, it states Consuls honoraires-C0.0. and COA.

What is meant with C0.0. and COA ? Are these abbreviations?

[image]

Secondly, before the main letter begins, the following is stated:

[image]

How would this part be translated in English?

Comment: Where is the Consuls honoraires-C0.0?

Comment: @grouah I have edited my question, including where C0.0 and COA appear. Do you have an idea what these represent?

Comment: The COA thing, for what it's worth, is an internal filing/reference number for the letter (so you can refer to it instead of referring to, say "your letter dated dd/mm/yyyy").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is meant with C0.0. and COA ?

The consul knows...

> Are these abbreviations?

Likely, and not common ones.

> How would this part be translated in English?

*Votre* and *vos* means "your", *du* means "of", *nos* means "our". The other words are essentially the same between French and English.

Comment: So we would say your communication between your references our references?

Comment: These are headers. Votre communication du 14 juillet 2020. Vos références : xyz, Nos références : COO/RVL/COA.01... Date : 20 juillet 2020